# Unexpected end of JSON input showNeg.js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am getting an error in some devices only.I am adding the error below.But i am sure that is not my code issue.the error is

```
VM114:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at showNeg.js:241
    at XMLHttpRequest.onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandler (showNeg.js:311)
(anonymous) @ showNeg.js:241
onDefaultReadyStateChangeHandler @ showNeg.js:311
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
showNag.NTServerCall @ showNeg.js:322
chkshowNeg @ showNeg.js:239
(anonymous) @ showNeg.js:47
showNeg.js:322 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://negbar.ad-blocker.org/chrome/adblocker-chrome-shownegJson.txt with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
showNag.NTServerCall @ showNeg.js:322
chkshowNeg @ showNeg.js:239
(anonymous) @ showNeg.js:47
```

I don't know why this happening

Comment: I'm seeing that as well, but can't narrow down the trigger.  Did you find what library this is coming from, and the issue behind it?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this ad blocker https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ad-blocker/kacljcbejojnapnmiifgckbafkojcncf is causing an issue. In order to prevent issue it has to be disabled in extension settings

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the issue is caused by the adblocker. However disabling the adblocker for the page you get this error (in my case was localhost:4200) did not fix it - I had to go to extensions and disable the whole extension.